# TYPO3 RealURL does not work with Plesk / IIS

Tags: http-status-code-404, typo3, realurl

I made a Website, which is based on TYPO3 with XAMPP.
Everything is working fine on my localhost.

Then I tried to copy the Website onto my Windows 2008 Server where I have Plesk and IIS running.

Now there is a problem with RealURL. In the browser, I get the symbolic URL like **/home** instead of **/index.php?id=2**, but it throws a **404 Page not found Error**

I copied the whole TYPO3 folder into my **htdocs folder** on the Server and made a **MySQL dump file**, which i then imported on the server too.

Opening the Website with the TYPO3 standard path works. (e.g. www.domain.com/**index.php?id=2**)

I really don't know what the issue is, because I also copied the **.htaccess** onto the Server, which is in the TYPO3 folder.

Is it a settings issue of Plesk or IIS? Does somebody know how to solve this? Would really appreciate if someone could give me some steps getting rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `mod_rewrite`, an apache module.
Since you work on ISS, you need to implement this in another way

Example: 
[how can I enable mod_rewrite on iis server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814768/how-can-i-enable-mod-rewrite-on-iis-server)

Comment: thanks for answering! does that mean, that my .htaccess in my TYPO3 folder has no effect to the mod_rewrite? (because in that file, the mod_rewrite is enabled)

Comment: Hey i just found out that i have IIS 6.1, but the mod_rewrite extension requires at least IIS 7.0, what can i do now? Im a bit scared that an update of IIS will cause a crash of my domain settings.

Comment: If you need to get TYPO3 running on IIS6 with realurl enabled, you need to research "ISAPIrewrite". There are some reports on how to get it working, but it seems that it will be not that easy.